# Quadratic reciprocity and Cox

Tags: number-theory

[Cox](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118390180) proves the following statement using quadratic reciprocity:

> If $D\equiv 0, 1\mod 4$ is a nonzero integer, then there is a unique homomorphism $\chi:(\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^*\to\{\pm 1\}$ such that $\chi([p]) = (D/p)$ for odd primes $p$ not dividing $D$.

Exercise 1.13 then asks to show that the above statement implies quadratic reciprocity, showing that the two are equivalent. The hint given is as follows:

> If $p$, $q$ are distinct odd primes, let $q^* = (-1)^{(q-1)/2}q$; then $q^*\equiv 1\mod{4}$, so that $(q^*/\cdot)$ gives a homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^*\to\{\pm 1\}$. $(\cdot/q)$ is also a homomorphism between these groups. Show that these two homomorphisms are the same.

The second homomorphism, $(./q)$, is obviously nontrivial. If we can show that the first is nontrivial, then the two must be equal, since they must both equal $-1$ on some generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^*$. But I can't see why (without using quadratic reciprocity or heavier machinery) the first map must be nontrivial.

So why is that true?

Comment: As it is your question is ill-posed. At first it is not at all obvious that $(\frac{D}{p})$ is periodic in $p$, that's the key of quadratic reciprocity, and it follows from expressing $\pm \sqrt{D}$ as a product of quadratic Gauss sums $\sum_{n=1}^m e^{2i \pi n^2/m}$.

Comment: @reuns In the text, the shaded statement is proved using quadratic reciprocity. This exercise is an attempt to show that the shaded statement is in fact equivalent to quadratic reciprocity. Although I understand your point, I don't think the question is ill-posed, since the shaded statement is assumed true in the exercise statement.

Comment: It is. Do you assume that for $q \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $p$ prime $f(p) = (\frac{q}{p})$ then $f(p_1) = f(p_2)$ when $q | p_1-p_2$ ? That $f(p_1)f(p_2) = f(p_3)$ when $q | p_1p_2-p_3$ ?

Comment: Yes. Clearly part of the assumption is that the given map is well-defined.

Comment: Another way of asking my question is: is there a simple way to see that if $q$ is an odd prime, then there is *some* odd prime $p$ such that $(q/p)=-1$?

Comment: No. But the proof of everything for $q$ prime $\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ is really not hard, starting from $\sum_{n=1}^q e^{2i \pi n^2/q} =\pm \sqrt{q}$

Comment: Yes, I realize that. Thanks. But clearly that wasn't the author's desired solution at this point in the book.

Comment: You meant some odd integer such that $q$ isn't a square $\bmod n$. That this is iff $q$ is a square is the first non-trivial case of the local global principle. The author probably meant to assume the map isn't trivial and realize there is a unique quadratic character modulo $q$

Comment: I think that's probably right.